# How can I reduce logical reads on self-join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, self-join

I have the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
LEFT(REPLACE(PEREWNOMETET.WNT_CODEARTICLE, 'P', ''), 5) AS CI, 
Reference

FROM WNOMETET AS PEREWNOMETET
JOIN WNOMELIG AS PEREWNOMELIG ON PEREWNOMELIG.WNL_NATURETRAVAIL = PEREWNOMETET.WNT_NATURETRAVAIL AND PEREWNOMELIG.WNL_ARTICLE = PEREWNOMETET.WNT_ARTICLE AND PEREWNOMELIG.WNL_MAJEUR = PEREWNOMETET.WNT_MAJEUR
JOIN WNOMELIG AS FILSWNOMELIG ON FILSWNOMELIG.WNL_ARTICLE=PEREWNOMELIG.WNL_COMPOSANT
JOIN ARTICLE AS COMPOSANT ON COMPOSANT.GA_ARTICLE=FILSWNOMELIG.WNL_COMPOSANT
JOIN APP_PIECES_RECHANGE ON Reference=FILSWNOMELIG.WNL_CODECOMPOSANT
WHERE COMPOSANT.GA_LIBREART1 = 'COM'
AND PEREWNOMETET.WNT_CODITI = 'STA'
```

And the following statistics :

```
(74944 ligne(s) affectée(s))
Table 'Worktable'. Nombre d'analyses 0, lectures logiques 0, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
Table 'APP_PIECES_RECHANGE'. Nombre d'analyses 1, lectures logiques 26, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
Table 'WNOMELIG'. Nombre d'analyses 10, lectures logiques 243780, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
Table 'ARTICLE'. Nombre d'analyses 5, lectures logiques 1062, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
Table 'WNOMETET'. Nombre d'analyses 5, lectures logiques 419, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Nombre d'analyses 0, lectures logiques 0, lectures physiques 0, lectures anticipées 0, lectures logiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures physiques de données d'objets volumineux 0, lectures anticipées de données d'objets volumineux 0.
```

My problem is about the logical reads (=lectures logiques) of the table "WNOMELIG".
The table is 1.67GB and the query is reading 1.86GB, which is too much. I would like to reduce the amount of logicial reads for this table but I don't really know how to do that.

There are two indexes on this table :

```
- Clustered Index : WNL_NATURETRAVAIL (ASC), WNL_ARTICLE (ASC), WNL_MAJEUR(ASC), WNL_GUID (ASC)
- Non Clustered Index : WNL_NATURETRAVAIL (ASC), WNL_COMPOSANT (ASC)
- Non Clustered Index : WNL_ARTICLE (ASC)
```

Execution plan :
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ2OpT78S

Could someone give me some insights about this issue ?
Thanks !

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the query logic would all help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you sample data. But the query is pretty simple.
You have 2 mains tables : WNOMETET and WNOMELIG. The fist one is basically just a header.
The second one is a parent-child structured table. That's why there is a self-join on this table.
The idea of the query is to show, for particular kind of header, all the childs.

Comment: Not sure how selective COMPOSANT.GA_LIBREART1 and  PEREWNOMETET.WNT_CODITI columns are, are they indexed?

Comment: Looks like you need an index on WNL_Article too

Comment: My bad, there is an index on WNL_Article, I forgot to mention it.
@PeterHe, they are not indexed, and they are pretty selective.

Comment: YOu have an index already on ERP].[dbo].[ARTICLE].[IX_ARTICLE].[COMPOSANT], but the statistics of the index is out of date: estimated 153264 rows, actual 610

Comment: Update the statistics of the index with full scan

Answer (score 0):

Two of your joins are not needed for your `SELECT` clause, but merely for lookup. You can hence put them in the `WHERE` clause where they belong in my opinion:

```
select distinct
  left(replace(wnt.wnt_codearticle, 'P', ''), 5) as ci, 
  fwnl.wnl_codea as reference
from wnometet as wnt
join wnomelig as pwnl on pwnl.wnl_naturetravail = wnt.wnt_naturetravail
                     and pwnl.wnl_article = wnt.wnt_article
                     and pwnl.wnl_majeur = wnt.wnt_majeur
join wnomelig as fwnl on fwnl.wnl_article = pwnl.wnl_a
where wnt.wnt_coditi = 'STA'
and fwnl.wnl_a in (select ga_article from article where ga_libreart1 = 'COM')
and fwnl.wnl_codea in (select reference from app_pieces_rechange);
```

Now check ...

- whether you really need to look up existence of a matching `app_pieces_rechange` row at all. Otherwise you can drop that clause.
- whether you still need `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is expensive, so whenever you can, try to avoid creating duplicates throughout your query in the first place.

And here are the indexes you may want to provide:

```
create idx01 on article (ga_libreart1, ga_article);
create idx02 on wnomelig (wnl_a, wnl_article, wnl_codea);
create idx03 on wnomelig (wnl_a, wnl_naturetravail, wnl_article, wnl_majeur);
create idx04 on wnomelig (wnl_article, wnl_a, wnl_codea);
create idx05 on wnomelig (wnl_naturetravail, wnl_article, wnl_majeur, wnl_a);
create idx06 on wnometet (wnt_coditi, wnt_naturetravail, wnt_article, wnt_majeur, wnt_codearticle);
create idx07 on wnometet (wnt_naturetravail, wnt_article, wnt_majeur, wnt_coditi, wnt_codearticle);
```

These are more indexes than needed, but the variety offers the DBMS multiple ways to run through the tables. Look at the execution plan to see which ones are used and drop the others.